# Get element attribute with .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple example table that has data attributes for every table row.

```
<table id="example">
  <tr data-sample="1">
    <th>Fox</th>
    <th>Sam</th>
    <th>Ted</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-sample="2">
    <td>Bill</td>
    <td>Nick</td>
    <td>Pal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-sample="3">
    <td>El</td>
    <td>Pal</td>
    <td>Tea</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to get all `data-sample` attributes with the following code:

```
('#example tr').each(function () {
    console.log(this.data('sample'));
});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkxwkro4/)

And I'm getting a "this.data is not a function" error. This gets me to the point that in .each jquery loop `this` returns a DOM element, not a function or whatever I can use a a selector (if I just print out `this`, I get a list of table rows and their children). Is there any way to get `this` as a selector? `('#example').children('tr')` and `('#example').find('tr')` give the same result.

Comment: `.data()` is jQuery ... `this` is a DOM element

Comment: Include jquery plugin. Please correct the data attr name . Its 'sample' not 'faculty'. $('#example tr').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).data('sample'));
});

Comment: updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wkxwkro4/1/

Comment: you can also select the data attribut:
`document.querySelectorAll('[data-sample]').forEach( _ => console.log(_.dataset.sample));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jquery syntax error**

`this` not jquery object .Do with `$(this).data('sample')`

```js
$('#example tr').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).data('sample'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
I have a simple example table that has data-attributes for every table row.

<table id="example">
  <tr data-sample="1">
    <th>Fox</th>
    <th>Sam</th>
    <th>Ted</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-sample="2">
    <td>Bill</td>
    <td>Nick</td>
    <td>Pal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-sample="3">
    <td>El</td>
    <td>Pal</td>
    <td>Tea</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Or** do with [`attr()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLyq6nwoXVAhUEMo8KHdgwAWoQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fattr%2F&usg=AFQjCNE1qhpJI2G8J0vSJXrZ_Vf8dTKrTg)

```
  $('#example tr').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('data-sample'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issue in you code:

1) you need to convert DOM object to jquery object for using with `.data()`

2) you are passing wrong property argument in `.data()`. it should be `sample`:

```
$('#example tr').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).data('sample'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 way to do this -

***#1***

```
$('#example tr').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).data('sample'));
});
```

***#2***

```
$('#example tr').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-sample'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#example tr').each(function () {             
                console.log($(this).attr("data-sample"));                   
            });
        });
```

If you want to get row content use this

```
$('#example tr').each(function (i) { 
   alert($('#example tr[data-sample]')[i].innerText.split("\t"));
});
```